# How to join 2 dataframes by two columns in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the difference in expected goals over the course of a soccer season. I have two dataframes which tell me 1) the opponents in each match, and 2) each team's expected goals per match, using a unique match id for each match in both dfs. I need to join these tables by both match id & team name.

```
match_opponents <- data.frame(home_team = c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3"),
away_team = c("Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 1"),
match_id = c("1111", "2222", "3333"))

team_xG <- data.frame(team_name = c("Team 1", "Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 3"),
expected_goals = c(1.1, 1.4, 2.3, 3.1, 2.1, 2.2),
match_id = c("1111", "3333", "1111", "2222", "2222", "3333"))
```

I would like to ultimately create an output table which shows for each team the expected goals scored & expected goals conceded over the course of the season, akin to:

```
xG_output <- data.frame(team_name = c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3"),
expected_goals_for = c(2.5, 5.4, 4.3),
expected_goals_against = c(4.5, 3.2, 4.5))
```

I have tried all sorts of left_joins and right_joins and everything to combine the two dataframes in a way that would allow me to build this last table, but I am struggling massively. Please let me know how I might go about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pivot your `match_opponents` data to a long format (matching the expected goals data), then join, then duplicate the `expected_goals` column but reversed within each match so that each row (for just 1 team in 1 match) has the goals scored for and against. Then we can sum by group to get the desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
match_opponents |>
  pivot_longer(-match_id, names_to = "locale", values_to = "team_name") |>
  left_join(team_xG, by = join_by(match_id, team_name)) |> 
  mutate(goals_against = rev(expected_goals), .by = match_id) |>
  summarize(
    expeced_goals_for = sum(expected_goals),
    expected_goals_against = sum(goals_against),
    .by = team_name
  )
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   team_name expeced_goals_for expected_goals_against
#   <chr>                 <dbl>                  <dbl>
# 1 Team 1                  2.5                    4.5
# 2 Team 2                  5.4                    3.2
# 3 Team 3                  4.3                    4.5
```